# My own hosted NuGet server doesn't work properly anymore

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, deprecated, nuget-server

I've hosted my own NuGet server, and it worked great for my libraries. In this case, I installed "NuGet.Server" package.

Recently, it doesn't work anymore and I can not push any version on it. When I've checked the issue, I found one of its dependencies which is "NuGet.Core", has been deprecated as it is legacy and is no longer maintained.

> **NuGet.Core**
>
> > This package has been deprecated as it is legacy and is no longer maintained.
>
> **Additional Details**
>
> > NuGet.Core is part of NuGet client v2 APIs. They have been replaced by NuGet client v3 and later APIs.

While installing "NuGet.Server" package, it still installing the deprecated package (NuGet.Core).

How do I host my own NuGet v3 server?

How to upgrade my existing NuGet servers to be v3 compatible?

Comment: Hello, I personally don't know NuGet.Server, but if possible, I would suggest you to migrate to a more recent and maintained alternative: BaGet (https://github.com/loic-sharma/BaGet)

Comment: The deprecated package message is just a warning, it wouldn't cause any errors. If you want to resolve the NuGet.Server issue we'll need more details, but migrating to a different server also works. BaGet is written by someone who works on nuget.org during the day, so it's a great choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NuGet.Core is a deprecated package, I've used BaGet which is written by someone who works on nuget.org, so it's a great choice.
My solution is:  [BaGet](https://github.com/loic-sharma/BaGet)